# Yet another movie line on the Linux terminal

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle

What famous quote does the following terminal session refer to?

```
$ ps -o ppid= -p $u
28342
$ echo $$
28342
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the YAML I know. =x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> "I am your father", Vader's famous quote to Luke from Star Wars: Episode V – The Empire Strikes Back (1980) ?

since

> I think the first command gives the pid of the parent of the specified process, and the second line confirms that the current process is that process.

Comment: Exactly right. For completeness you should also give the movie title, although I guess everyone will immediately know it after reading the quote.

Comment: True, edited to include movie title and character details nonetheless

Comment: Actually, Darth Vader *doesn't* say "Luke, I am your father" - he says "No, I am your father".  https://youtu.be/RgDPi5WvC8M?t=92

Comment: My answer doesn't say Luke either... What exactly are you correcting?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, I think it's

> "We're the same, you and me. We're the same, don't you see?" from *Falling Down, 1993* 
>  Reasoning: Your first command gives the pid of the process designated by **$u**. The second command gives the pid of the current bash process that you are running. Since both pid's are equivalent,  u (**you**) and the current bash session (**me**) are the **same**.

Comment: Sorry, but your description of what the first command does is wrong, and consequently so is your conclusion. But you also got quite a few things right.